# How can I make gitlab suppress powershell input from the job log?

Tags: powershell, gitlab

I’ve set up a runner on a Windows 10 laptop. Worker type `shell`. In all steps of the job we can see under-the-hood gitlab commands being executed with local echo on the terminal. Included here are secrets such as “GITLAB_CI_RELEASE_SSH_KEY”. I don’t want this in my log. It totals to over 1000 lines and makes finding the important output lines difficult.

Log excerpt (highly truncated) from the step “Getting source from Git repository”:

```
PS C:\jobs> & {
>> 
>> $ErrorActionPreference = "Stop"
>> $FF_CMD_DISABLE_DELAYED_ERROR_LEVEL_EXPANSION="false"
>> $env:FF_CMD_DISABLE_DELAYED_ERROR_LEVEL_EXPANSION=$FF_CMD_DISABLE_DELAYED_ERROR_LEVEL_EXPANSION
>> $FF_NETWORK_PER_BUILD="false"
>> $env:FF_NETWORK_PER_BUILD=$FF_NETWORK_PER_BUILD
>> $FF_USE_LEGACY_KUBERNETES_EXECUTION_STRATEGY="false"
>> $env:FF_USE_LEGACY_KUBERNETES_EXECUTION_STRATEGY=$FF_USE_LEGACY_KUBERNETES_EXECUTION_STRATEGY
>> $FF_USE_DIRECT_DOWNLOAD="true"
>> $env:FF_USE_DIRECT_DOWNLOAD=$FF_USE_DIRECT_DOWNLOAD
```

edit: Gitlab is looking for `pwsh` so I created this `pwsh.cmd` to launch powershell: `powershell.exe -NoExit -Command C:\myproj\powershell_init_gitlab_worker.ps1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was that Gitlab was looking for `pwsh`. The correct solution was to change to the following line under the `[[runners]]` section of `config.toml`

```
shell = "powershell"
```

Instead I had done a fault workaround by providing `pwsh.cmd` that launched Powershell in an incorrect manner (see updated question).

I will leave this answer here in case someone else does the same stupid mistake as me